# relocation target runtime.entersyscallblock not defined for ABI0

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to compile a project under GoLang and I got an error with the building.
in fact, the error is:

> vendor/github.com/google/netstack/tcpip/link/rawfile.blockingPoll:relocation target runtime.entersyscallblock not defined for ABI0 (but is defined for ABIInternal).

I was under **goLang 12** and on the internet it says that it has some **assembly's issue**.
so I downloaded **goLang 10.8** and re-tried the process but unfortunately, the error persists.

Does anyone have an idea, on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the docker file code and how you are downloading dependencies etc details!

Answer (score 0):

I removed  vendor/github.com/google/netstack and i cloned it back from github and it worked ...